# fileevent in tcl is not working while receiving udp data. How to do it?

Tags: tcl

I am sending udp packets from one pc to other using udp package provided by tcl. At the receiver side i have created a filevent such that whenever there is data on the udp port it should call the handler to read the data. But when i run my receiver script, nothing happens untill i mention wait forever in the script. I want a functionality that, whenever there is data present on udp port i want to read it. Please tell me how i can do it. Here are my sender and receiver scripts.

sender script named "udp_sender_script.tcl" :

```
namespace eval soc {
variable s
}

set soc::s [udp_open]
udp_conf $soc::s $IP_ADDR_RX  $UDP_PORT
fconfigure $soc::s -buffering none -translation binary

set data 1234
append hex [ format %04X [ expr $i | 0x8000 ] ]
append hex [ format %08X [ expr $data ] ]

while { 1 } {
after 500
puts -nonewline $soc::s [binary format H* $hex]
}
```

udp script named "udp_receiver_script.tcl"

```
proc udp_listen {} {
set pkt [read $soc::s ]
if { $pkt > 0 } {
puts "received string is $pkt"
}
return 0
}

proc every { ms body } {
eval $body; after $ms [info level 0]}

if { $argc < 1 } {
puts "ERROR! Please give udp port number as an argument while running the script"
} else {
set UDP_PORT [lindex $argv 0]
set  soc::s [udp_open $UDP_PORT]
fconfigure $soc::s -buffering none -translation binary
fileevent $soc::s readable [list ::udp_listen $soc::s]
}
```

When instead of using fileevent if i read the data on udp port in while loop in receiver script, i get the data. But i don't to unnecessarily use while loop. Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Unless your second snippet is not really complete, you miss one crucial point: for any type of events, including those set up with `fileevent`, to work the Tcl runtime have to *"enter the event loop".* This suspends the execution of the script which made Tcl enter the event loop, and further processing of Tcl code is done *only* in response to various events being generated. The normal processing resumes when the event loop is left by the runtime.

In a program which does not use Tk, the event loop is normally entered using the [`vwait`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/vwait.htm) ("wait for a variable until it's written") command, and it's done [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12198748/720999). See also [this](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1757) and generally search [the wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/) for the "event" keyword.

I also highly recommend reading ["Building High Performance Networking Servers using Tcl"](http://www.maplefish.com/todd/tcl_net_idioms.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply kostix. But i am also using Tk. So if i enter into any event loop, it will stop normal processing of my GUI unless the event loop is left at runtime. This is what i really don't want. I am i correct??

Comment: @user1497818, no, Tk has its event loop already started and entered. You can think of your "top level" code which runs when `wish` executes your script as called from that event loop. This also means your problem might lie somewhere else... Are you sure you don't *block* in some other (Tk?) callback code after you have set up your file event handler?

Comment: And if that is the case, is there any way to do this?? I have tried for creating a tcl thread for this but that is not working for me. Please tell me if you have a proper way to read the data which is coming randomly on udp port.

Comment: @user1497818, no theads do not fit for this case. file events work with the UDP package just OK (I'm using it in production code). Again, can you guarantee you do not do busy-waiting in some other callback code? Stop asking about "proper way to..." -- you've already been provided with working examples.

Comment: Actually i am yet to integrate this part of my code with the TK code. I just want to check independently the functionality of whether any data which comes on udp port can be read without loss. And in doing this i just need to make sure that whatever code i will be using should be comfortable to use with the main GUI tk code whenever i will start integrating the blocks. So can you suggest any method to check in this regard. And do you mean that when i use the above receiver script with the TK code, it will be actually invoked from the event loop?? Then will my other work int he tk code stop?

Comment: @user1497818, yes, it will work. Tk is just one client of the Tcl's event loop -- nothing special from the point of view of the event loop implementation itself. As to checking whether it would work... I really fail to see any problem here: just write a dead simple Tk application and check. Basically, converting an app like yours to use GUI amounts to adding `package require Tk` above the code and removing `vwait whatever` call at the end of the code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23081/discussion-between-kostix-and-user1497818)

Comment: Sorry i have restricted access here. Not able to open the chat link